# Stubbing Paperclip S3 requests in specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, stubbing

I am using Paperclip and S3 for image uploads and am trying to stub out calls to S3 from my test suite.  I found the thoughtbot post which mentions doing

```
  a.cover       { a.paperclip_fixture('album', 'cover', 'png') }
```

but that gives me a "wrong number of arguments (4 for 2)" error.  I tried switching the arguments above to an array, which removes the original error, but gives an error saying "Attribute already defined: paperclip_fixture".

Has anyone been able to get this working?  Also, I'd ideally like to use the local filesystem for the development environment.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Could you post more info about your code please? For example, what is a.cover? I'm assuming that a is your object, and cover is the attribute containing the URI to the image?

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to test? It would help to have more context here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using shoulda?  If you aren't using shoulda the paperclip_fixture method that you're using may come from somewhere else and thus behave differently.

Potentially relevant: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/shoulda_macros/paperclip.rb

Comment: @Eric M. What code did you add to actually make this work? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @Eric M. @Eliza @Peter Nixey Was there a straightforward solution to this problem? I have tried various strategies include to `Paperclip::Shoulda` at various stages with no luck. Any follow-on suggestions?

Comment: @sorens - no idea I'm afraid. I moved on from this

Answer (score 7):

Okay, I've got the basic issue figured out.  This is (I believe) as Eliza said, because I'm not using `shoulda` (I'm using `rspec 2.6.0` and `factory_girl 2.1.2`).

Here's what worked for me (where `Profile` is the class that has attachements):

```
  Profile.any_instance.stub(:save_attached_files).and_return(true)
  @profile = Factory(:profile)
```

At the moment I just have this right in my `before` method of my `rspec` example.  There's probably a better place to put it.

Answer (score 7):

With latest paperclip(from github master branch) and aws-sdk version 2, I solved my issue with following configuration :

```
require "aws-sdk"
Aws.config[:s3] = {stub_responses: true}
```

For more information, please take a look at [amazon sdk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ClientStubs.html#stub_responses-instance_method)

Answer (score 5):

Placing this in my 'spec/rails_helper.rb' file worked for me:

```
require 'aws'
AWS.stub!
AWS.config(:access_key_id => "TESTKEY", :secret_access_key => "TESTSECRET")
```

Answer (score 3):

Many of these techniques don't seem to work with the latest paperclip and S3.  What finally worked for me is the combination of:

```
AWS.config(:access_key_id => "TESTKEY", :secret_access_key => "TESTSECRET", :stub_requests => true)
```

and

```
Mymodel.any_instance.stubs(:save_attached_files).returns(true)
```

But, actually, all you really need to do in many cases is the AWS :stub_requests and it will achieve what you want.

Comment: I started with your idea, and then, reading [the v2 documentation for the `Aws::Client` class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ClientStubs.html) decided that this works better: `Aws.config = {stub_responses: true}`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got this working. First you have to have the fakeweb gem or it will fail. You also have to have an empty file in the `spec/support/paperclip/[model]/[attachment_name][ext]` path.

What I did was to copy the code from Paperclip and paste it into my factory. I was unable to get the 'paperclip_fixture' working.

```
factory :attachment do
  file do |a|
    # Stubbed  Paperclip attachment from: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/shoulda_macros/paperclip.rb#L68
    # FIX: This was the only way I made this work. Calling the paperclip_fixture directly didn't work.
    # See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941586/stubbing-paperclip-s3-requests-in-specs
    model, attachment, extension = "customer_attachment", "file", "doc"      
    definition = model.gsub(" ", "_").classify.constantize.
                       attachment_definitions[attachment.to_sym]

    path = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/:id/#{definition[:path]}"
    path.gsub!(/:([^\/\.]+)/) do |match|
      "([^\/\.]+)"
    end

    begin
      FakeWeb.register_uri(:put, Regexp.new(path), :body => "OK")
    rescue NameError
      raise NameError, "the stub_paperclip_s3 shoulda macro requires the fakeweb gem."
    end
    base_path = File.join(Rails.root, "spec", "support", "paperclip")
    File.new(File.join(base_path, model, "#{attachment}.#{extension}"))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I stub a file from paperclip without using the shoulda helpers.

```
before(:each) do 
  @sheet = double('sheet')
  @sheet.stub(:url).and_return(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec','fixtures','files', 'file.xls'))
  active_record_object.stub(:sheet).and_return(@sheet)
end
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this upgrading an app from Rails 2.3 to Rails 3.0 after having followed [Testing Paperclip on S3 with Cucumber & Factory Girl](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/testing-paperclip-s3).

Instead of including the Paperclip::Shoulda module into the Factory class, I had to include it into the FactoryGirl::DefinitionProxy class, so I changed this:

```
class Factory
  include Paperclip::Shoulda
end
```

to

```
class FactoryGirl::DefinitionProxy
  include Paperclip::Shoulda
end
```

For reference, I'm using paperclip 2.4.1 and factory_girl 2.0.5.